# Multiple overloaded methods: Does null equal NullPointerException?

Tags: java, reference, nullpointerexception, null, overloading

```
public class TestMain {

    public static void methodTest(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception method called");
    }

    public static void methodTest(Object e) {
        System.out.println("Object method called");
    }

    public static void methodTest(NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("NullPointerException method called");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        methodTest(null);
    }   
}
```

Output: NullPointerException method called

Comment: What happens if you use `methodTest((Object)null);`? or `methodTest((Exception)null);`?

Comment: if methodTest((Object)null) is used then output is "Object method called".
if methodTest((Exception)null) is used then output is "Exception method called".

Comment: So `null` isn't a `NullPointerException`, why the compiler is choosing to call that method when the call is ambiguous, I don't know.

Comment: There really should be a compiler warning here...

Comment: Compiler warning is not thrown and should be fine with methodTest(null).
However,
methodTest((Object)null) and methodTest((Exception)null) should get a compiler warning but even that is missing

Comment: Note: The term for this is [method overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading).

Comment: Why do you believe that should that get a compiler warning?  Can you explain your thinking here?  Suppose that instead of exceptions, the methods took Object, Fruit and Banana, where Fruit derives from Object and Banana derives from Fruit. Would you expect a warning in that case too?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If there are several overloaded methods that might be called with a given parameter (`null` in your case) the compiler chooses the most specific one.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5

In your case `methodTest(Exception e)` is more specific than `methodTest(Object e)`, since Exception is a subclass of Object. And `methodTest(NullPointerException e)` is even more specific.

If you replace NullPointerException with another subclass of Exception, the compiler will choose that one.

On the other hand, if you make an additional method like `testMethod(IllegalArgumentException e)` the compiler will throw an error, since it doesn't know which one to choose.

Comment: Wrong when `IllegalArgumentException` is used it will call the `methodTest(Exception e)`.

Comment: @Runcorn Did you actually try that? It works as described by my answer here.

Comment: Complier throws an error if both public static void methodTest(NullPointerException e) {
  System.out.println("NullPointerException method called");
 }

 public static void methodTest(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
  System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException method called");
 }
  are present and prints "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException method called " if only public static void methodTest(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
  System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException method called");
 }
 is present

Comment: Ah!!! Sorry I thought you were talking about the Parameter not the Method. So, you are right!!

Comment: But why is `NullPointerException` "more specific" to `null` than `Exception`? Does `null` inherit from `Exception`? Does `null` inherit from everything?

Comment: @PatrickCollins NullPointerException is not more specific to null, it is more specific than Exception, meaning a smaller subset of all possible parameters are valid for this one than for Exception. null is just a possible value for all three methods.

Comment: @PatrickCollins *"Does null inherit from everything?"* The null type has a single value, `null`, which can be converted to any other reference type. That's how it works in Java.

Comment: @ThomasStets Ah, okay. So `null` will convert to whatever is farthest away from `Object` in the inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: @PatrickCollins yes, if you have only one path through the hierarchy. If there are several possible hierarcies (A extends Object, B extends A, C extends Object) the compiler will balk, since it doesn't know which branch to choose.

Comment: I believe the answer should also explain *why*, when using null as argument, this ends up in having NullPointerException as the most specific match. John Jaques's answer adds this information.

Comment: @PatrickCollins: You are using the word "inherit" in a strange way; a type *inherits* from another when a derived type has all the members of a base type.  I think you are using "inherit" to mean "is implicitly convertible to", which is a very different thing. Null is *implicitly convertible* to many types but that doesn't mean that a null expression is of a type that has all the *members* of every other type.

Comment: @PatrickCollins: To address our question "null will convert to whatever is farthest away from object?" -- sort of. The better way to think about it is: null is convertible to many types. Of those conversions, some are *better* than others. A conversion to a *more specific* type is *better* than a conversion to a *less specific* type. The job of overload resolution is to deduce the *best* method given a bunch of -- possibly contradictory -- "betterness" relationships amongst the various conversions.

Comment: @PatrickCollins: So for example if you had types Object, Animal, Turtle, and Banana, with the obvious relationships between them, and overloads that took Object, Turtle and Banana, Turtle does not win because it is farther from Object than Banana. Rather, neither would win. Turtle is more specific than Object, so that eliminates Object, but neither Turtle nor Banana is more specific than the other, so neither would be "best", and overload resolution would give an error.

Answer (score 9):

The compiler will try to match with the most specific parameter, which in this case is `NullPointerException`. You can see more info in the Java Language Specification, section [15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)
:

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than
>   another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed
>   on to the other one without a compile-time type error.
>
> [...]

Comment: In [Java Puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/) by Joshua Bloch and Neal Gafter, there is a puzzle dedicated to this "most-specific method" behavior.