# Null is of reference type, is it a String reference or Object reference?

Tags: java, oop, object

`null` is a reference and it is of `null` type only, i.e. `null` is not object type.
But, when I run the following code snippet I was surprised when I pass null to method `method(null);` it calls `method(String s)` not `method(Object o)`.

If `null` is itself a type defined by Java and not object type, then why does it call `method(String s)` not `method(Object o)`?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method(null);
    }
    public static void method(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Object impl");
    }
    public static void method(String s) {
        System.out.println("String impl");
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

I have added one more method:

```
public static void method(Integer s) {
   System.out.println("String impl11");
}
```

Now the compiler gives the error `The method method(Object) is ambiguous for the type Test`.

```
Integer a = null;
```

If it is legal, then why do I see a compile-time exception?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470540/does-this-mean-null-equals-nullpointerexception

Comment: @ThomasStets I don't find it is dublicate qustion

Comment: @Priya It is. Read the question, it asks exactly the same thing, except for method parameters having different type.

Comment: It is basically the same question: overloaded methods, called with a null parameter, why does it call this one and not that. And the answer is also the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`null` is assignable to any reference type. When it comes to method overloading, the compiler always prefers the method with the more specific argument types. Therefore the method with the `String` argument is preferred over the method with the `Object` argument, since `String` is a sub-class of `Object`.

If, on the other hand, the choice was between methods with unrelated argument types - for example `method(String s)` and `method (Integer i)` - the code wouldn't pass compilation, since none of the options would have precedence over the other.

Comment: @Priya I already edited the answer to address your edit.

Comment: means `String`, `Integer` ..... are subclases of object class that's why compiler confused which method to call, is it right?

Comment: @Priya neither String is a sub-class of Integer nor Integer a sub-class or String. Therefore, the compiler has no preference between the two.

Comment: Thanks for answering to my quation.